# How To Create User's Virtualization Environment

Tags: virtualization, linux, users, resource-management, containers

what i want to do is to create user virtulized environment  (online)

i want to create an environment that my user connect to my server online & they will have there own online pc .. may be its ssh or Virtulized Desktop

1st i did research on Linux containers (openvz)..i did it on Red Hat 5 & i havent done on ubuntu

how to i make a user virtulized environment for my user's , i have 5 users that i want to give them online desktop through DDNS

i want my user to have separate Desktop just like Linux Containers

## UPDATE

i want my user to connect to my server through DDNS

I want my users to have to have a separate OS when they connect to my server + quota limit on them for disk space

i want per user to use 15% of my server resources

& i want my users to have GUI & Non GUI environment when they connect to my sever ( like desktop sharing or connect through ssh )

Comment: It is hard to tell what you're asking, and unless you take the effort to clarify, you'll probably see some votes to close.

Comment: Updated.........

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: yes i m looking at it ty

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I'll take a swing.

My interpretation is that you want to allow a small number of people to log into a desktop environment on your server.

Unless there's reason not to, just create them user accounts on your server, set up VNC (pref. through a ssh tunnel) and be done with it.

Setting up a VM for each user will create a significant amount of overhead.  OpenVZ is better about resources than a traditional VM, but there is still overhead.  Unless you expect all of your users on at the same time and want to prevent them from hogging resources (which is a valid concern), you're making more work than necessary.

#### Update

(After question clarification)

Create separate VirtualBox VMs (with VNC and SSH), size them appropriately for RAM and Disk, and Have a look at `VBoxManage modifyvm --cpuexecutioncap` to limit the processor utilization.

Another option which may be better for your users is to `nice` each virtualbox process so that it takes a lower processor priority.  This allows them to run at full speed if nothing is going on, but yield to other processes when needed.

To make this setup easier, you may want to check out the Ruby Gem "[Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/)".

Comment: thank you i have Updated My ? hope now u will understand